# Order output using fileOutputStream Java

Tags: java

I am messing about with some code and was wondering is there a way to order the output in an ascending/descending order using the fileOutputStream?

code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String directory = "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\Files\\ex1.txt"; 
    String output = "C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Desktop\\Files\\ex1_temp.txt";
    BufferedInputStream readFile = null;  
     BufferedOutputStream writeFile = null;  
      try {  
       readFile = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(directory));  
       writeFile = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output));  
       int data;  
       while ((data = readFile.read()) != -1) {  
        //System.out.println(data);  
        //Collections.sort(data);
        writeFile.write(data);  
       }  
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
       e.printStackTrace();  
      } finally {  
       if (readFile != null)  
        readFile.close();  
       if (writeFile != null)  
        writeFile.close();  
      }  
     }
```

Comment: The data will be appear in the order you write it. It's not clear why you're reading/writing a single byte at a time, but basically you'll need to read the data, sort it, then write it.

Comment: I am messing about with the code. I got a large file >2gb that needs to be read, and was reading that the best way handling such files without any memory issues is using the fileinput/outputstream.  Not sure how true it is but always worth trying, only way to learn :)

Comment: @MubeenHussain "but always worth trying, only way to learn" Look I don't know you, but this sounds dangerously close to something a copy/paste programmer would say. Please, stay off that path. Try to understand things too before you try them out, otherwise how would you know what to expect from your experiment? http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/87696/is-copy-paste-programming-bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you need to have the data in memory to sort them, so you can't use streams well for that.

If you need to sort large data, you can use [External sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting). While implementing such algorithm, you'll probably end up using streams (to read the original file in smaller chunks etc.), but streams alone won't help you here, they're merely part of the solution.